# Average revenue per member from January within 1 month and 2 months of the signup date

Tags: mysql, average

I need to calculate the average revenue per member that signed up in January within 1 month and 2 months of their signup date.

Only using SELECT statements to provide the output(no temporary tables or functions). Also looking for MYSQL syntax

I have 2 tables.

```
Table: memberships, Columns:

member_id int PK
signup_date datetime
join_country varchar(2)
email varchar(45)
cancellation_date date
expiry_date date

Table: transactions, Columns:

transaction_id int PK
member_id int
transaction_date datetime
transaction_type_ID int
product_id int
transaction_amount float
```

```sql
SELECT m.member_id, m.signup_date, AVG(t.transaction_amount)
FROM memberships m
INNER JOIN transactions t
ON m.member_id = t.member_id
WHERE m.signup_date = '2018-01-01'
AND t.transaction_date >= '2018-01-01' AND t.transaction_date < '2018-03-01';
```

Comment: Edited the post. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "within 1 month and 2 months"? Do you want the revenue for each month?

Answer (score 0):

You're only doing members who signed up on January 1, not during the entire month of January. Similarly, you're calculating 2 months from January 1, not their actual signup dates.

You're not calculating the average per member, you're calculating the average per transaction. You need a subquery that gets the total revenue per member, then the main query can get the average of this.

You're not grouping the revenue by month, so not producing separate results for 1 month and 2 months after signing up.

```
SELECT month, AVG(total) AS avg_revenue
FROM (
    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, m.signup_date, t.transaction_date)+1 AS month,
            SUM(t.transaction_amount) AS total
    FROM mindgeek.memberships m
    INNER JOIN mindgeek.transactions t
    ON m.member_id = t.member_id AND t.transaction_date < DATE_ADD(m.signup_date, INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
    WHERE m.signup_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31'
    GROUP BY m.member_id, month
) AS per_member
GROUP BY month
```

I add `1` to the result of `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` because it returns the number of full months, rounding down. So the period from signup to 1 month later returns `0`.